# pass the selected value of combo box as a parameter to specific php function using ajax or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

Hi First i will explain what i am trying to do so that everyone will have a clear understanding of what i am trying to do.

I am developing an application using laravel framework,in which i have an edit page and a php page namely edit.blade.php and calculation.php

**edit.blade.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CompanyDepreciationCalculation()
    {
        debugger;
        var endFinancialYear = $('#years').val();
        $('.display-table').html("<?php DepreciationCalculation2014(endFinancialYear); ?>");
    }
</script>

<div class="page-header">
    <h3>@lang('general.calculate_2014')</h3>
    <div class="pull-right">

    </div>
</div>

<div class="row form-wrapper">
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="calculation.php" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('years') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <label for="shift" class="col-md-3 control-label calculate-label">@lang('admin/records/form.Calculate_dep')</label>
            <div class="controls col-md-7">
                <select name="years" class="controls assettext select2" id="years"  >
                    <option value=""> -- Select Year -- </option>
                    <?php
                    for ($i = 2014; $i <= 2101; $i++) {
                        echo "<option value=" . $i . ">" . $i . "</option>";
                    }
                    ?> 
                </select>
                <!--<a  class="btn btn-flat gray pull-right generatebtn">Next</a>-->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-flat gray pull-right generatebtn" id="next" value="next" onclick="CompanyDepreciationCalculation()"><i class="icon-download-alt"></i>Generate  Depreciation Report</button>
            </div>
            {{ $errors->first('shift', '<span class="alert-msg"><i class="icon-remove-sign"></i> :message</span>') }}
        </div>
        <div  class="display-table" style="margin:70px 0px 0px -14px;">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here i have a drop down with id years and i try to get the selected value from the drop down and pass the value to the php function DepreciationCalculation2014 as a parameter and display the calculated values in a table on the event of a button click.The calculation and table stuffs are written inside the function DepreciationCalculation2014.

In my calculation.php page i have many functions where one of the function name is DepreciationCalculation2014 which i have specified in edit page as php function and i have included the php file in form tag of edid page.First of all i do know whether it is a good way of calling the  php function like this.

**calculation.php**

```
function DepreciationCalculation2014($endFinancialYear) 
{ 
    //calculation stuff goes here and i display the calculated values in a table
}
```

The problem is i can't get the variable here and it throws the following error

```
Use of undefined constant selectedYear - assumed 'selectedYear' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\AMS\app\views\backend\calculate2014\index.blade.php)
```

I tried using ajax with no luck

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $('#years').change(function() {debugger;
        $.POST('depreciationcalculation.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    });
});
```

and in php page

```
function DepreciationCalculation2014($endFinancialYear = 2014) 
{ 
    $_POST['years']
}
```

please help me to solve this issue i know that i am doing some thing wrong but not so clear about it.

Answer (score 0):

This part is surely bad:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CompanyDepreciationCalculation() {   
    debugger;
    var endFinancialYear = $('#years').val();
    $('.display-table').html("<?php DepreciationCalculation2014(endFinancialYear); ?>");
  } 
</script>
```

You can not pass a javascript variable like this to the php

```
$('.display-table').html("<?php DepreciationCalculation2014(endFinancialYear); ?>");
```

use ajax instead.

Comment: can u be bit more clear how to achieve it through ajax  with an example because iam not sure how to mention the function name and pass the parameter in ajax.